# HttpClient not responding correctly to FIN, PSH, ACK from web server? Leads to TaskCanceledException

Tags: .net, tcp, httpclient, wireshark, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient.SendAsync()` and having an issue that happens from time to time. The files I am POSTing are really small, and I have set the time out to 5 seconds. I'm using the same HttpClient throughout the lifetime of the application, and requests are done infrequently.

It usually goes fine, but some times I get a "Task cancelled exception".

From what I can gather, the communication always ends with a `RST`, `ACK` from the client, and it happens after the server sends a `200 OK` with `FIN`, `PSH`, `ACK` flags.

[image: When it fails]
[image: When it fails 2]

When the server sends the `200 OK` with only `PSH`, `ACK` everything works fine.

[image: When everything works fine]
[image: When everything works fine 2]

Anybody got any idea as to why this fails, or what I can try differently?